# terraform with DynamoDB backend: 400 Bad Request when creating new workspace

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have terraform stack which keeps locks in DynamoDB:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket  = "bucketname"
    key     = "my_key"
    encrypt = "true"
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::11111111:role/my_role"
    dynamodb_table = "tf-remote-state-lock"
  }
}
```

When I run `terraform workspace new test` it fails with (quite misleading) error:

```
failed to lock s3 state: 2 errors occurred:
* ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found
* ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found
```

If I turn on `TF_LOG=DEBUG` then I see `400 Bad Request` (more details [on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/4sbuVj0S))

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Does the table exist in your account? And can that role access it?

Comment: Definitely yes and yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: `terraform workspace whatsoever` should rum only AFTER `terraform init`. If you have `TF_WORKSPACE` set up, you may have error during `tf init` saying that the workspace does not exist yet, so you may have temptation to rum `tf ws new` before `tf init`. Don't do it, just **set up `TF_WORKSPACE` only after `tf init`.**

Answer (score 0):

Probably you did not create your AWS resources. The [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/s3.html) says the following about the s3 bucket:

> This assumes we have a bucket created called mybucket.

I think the second message comes from the DynamoDb table not created or not configured correctly. The documentation says the following about using the DynamoDb for locking and consistentcy:

> dynamodb_table - (Optional) Name of DynamoDB Table to use for state
> locking and consistency. The table must have a primary key named
> LockID with type of string. If not configured, state locking will be
> disabled.